# Expression Tree. Check if the property is null before executing the method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, tree, expression

I have an expression tree. Everything works fine when using operators like "Contains" or "Equals"
However, in some cases, the property that is being compared to is null (retrieved from the database).

For example, I have an object like this:

```
public class Customer
{
public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
public virtual string Address{ get; set; }
public virtual string City{ get; set; }
}
```

The user has decided to filter the results return on Customer.Address. However, some records retrieved from the database are null. Then when my Compiled expression executes and an instance of 'Customer' is passed to the expression, it fails and returns the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here is what I have to make the expression:

```
var wPropertyExp = Expression.Property(wParameterExp,"Address");
var wMethod = wDataType.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
var wConstantExpression = Expression)Expression.Constant("Test",typeof(string));
wMethodCall = Expression.Convert(wPropertyExp, typeof(string));

wExpression = Expression.Call(wMethodCall, wMethod, wConstantExpression);

wAllExpressions.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(wExpression, wParameterExp));
```

So these expressions get .Compile() and then an instance of Customer is passed. Address is null and everything blows up. How can I implement a way to check if Customer.Address is != null before running the 'Equals' expression against the object?

Comment: If you're compiling the expression then you're not allowing the query provider to translate the expressions into SQL that is executed in the database, which is *the whole point of using expressions in the first place*.  If you're just going to use LINQ to objects, you almost certainly don't need to use `Expression` at all.  When translated to SQL it won't be a problem as equality checks in SQL just propagate null.

Comment: I have a list of objects returned via nhibernate.
I have created a Filter control which then generates expressions based on databases columns, operators and search criteria. Everything is then converted to an expression tree and then the results are filtered based on that.

Comment: None of that changes my comment.  Either you want this operation to be executed within the databse, in which case you need to not compile the expression, or you really do want this to be done in LINQ to objects, in which case you have no reason to be using `Expression` trees in the first place; just write the code as regular code.

Comment: So this cannot be salvaged? It's a re-write?

Comment: Well if you want the query to be evaluated on the database and not all done in memory just *don't compile the expression*.  Not compiling it isn't going to require a full re-write.  If you really want it all done in memory and not on the database then there are far, far easier ways of doing that than using expressions; it would take you far less effort to re-write it than you've spent getting this far.

Comment: Can you steer me in the right direction as how to implement something like that? A way to loop through a list of Customer objects and determine if an object meets the condition.

Comment: `var query = customers.Where(customer => customer.Address == "Test");`